# Using SELECT CASE WHEN, to select only a subset of a column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to select a subset of a column val from a table where the subset is in a time range and the row also has an index value of 23. I'm currently using CASE to specify that Index=23 and the DateAndTime should be equal to my counting variable for days(d@daycnt) and counting variable for hours @hourcnt.

```
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Index=23 
    AND DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DateAndTime)=@daycnt
    AND DATEPART(HOUR,DateAndTime)=@hourcnt THEN Val END
    FROM Table
```

When I use the above code, I select the whole column Val. I've been trying to add a where condition after the THEN to specify the subset of Val that  I want as below:

```
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Index=23 
    AND DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DateAndTime)=@daycnt
    AND DATEPART(HOUR,DateAndTime)=@hourcnt THEN Val WHERE 

    Index=23 
    AND DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DateAndTime)=@daycnt
    AND DATEPART(HOUR,DateAndTime)=@hourcnt END
    FROM Table
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to specify the subset of a column after the THEN.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause follows the `FROM` in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Can you provide sample data, and expected value?

Comment: Why exactly are you using a CASE statement. It seems that a simple query should do what you want. Can you explain why `SELECT Val FROM Table WHERE Index=23 AND DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DateAndTime)=@daycnt AND DATEPART(HOUR,DateAndTime)=@hourcnt` wasn't used on the first example?

Comment: To add a little more context, I'm using 4 of these SELECT statements in an INSERT INTO statement. INSERT INTO #temptable (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) SELECT CASE WHEN Index=23  AND DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DateAndTime)=@daycnt
 AND DATEPART(HOUR,DateAndTime)=@hourcnt THEN Val END. Ditto for the 3 other SELECT statements where index is another value

Comment: So I didn't use the `SELECT Val FROM Table WHERE Index=23 AND DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DateAndTime)=@daycnt AND DATEPART(HOUR,DateAndTime)=@hourcnt` because it doesn't properly fill the columns of my temporary table within the INSERT INTO

Answer (score 0):

Using a case statement will give you a result with all rows, but Val will only show if your `CASE` condition is met.

> Update: You said you would like the value to show in a different col, depending on your criteria.  This could be done with a CASE or UNION. I think the UNION is easier to read and troubleshoot. I will show both solutions and let you decide.

It sounds like you only want to include the matching rows. If that is what you want, then don't use `CASE`. Instead put your filter in the `WHERE` clause.

Example Data:

```
Index  Val    DateAndTime      
-----  ---    -----------------
  5     6      9/24/2018 10:01 
  9     1      9/24/2018 10:01 
 23     9      9/24/2018 10:01 
 23    12      9/24/2018 10:01 
 25     4      9/24/2018 10:01
```

Your query using `CASE`:

```
SELECT Index, 
       CASE Index WHEN 5 THEN Val ELSE NULL END AS Col1, 
       CASE Index WHEN 9 THEN Val ELSE NULL END AS Col2,
       CASE Index WHEN 23 THEN Val ELSE NULL END AS Col3,
       CASE Index WHEN 25 THEN Val ELSE NULL END AS Col4,
       DateAndTime
FROM Table
WHERE DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DateAndTime)=@daycnt
  AND DATEPART(HOUR,DateAndTime)=@hourcnt
```

Gives this result:

```
Index  Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4    DateAndTime
-----  ----   ----   ----   ----    -----------------
  5      6    null   null   null    9/24/2018 10:01
  9    null     1    null   null    9/24/2018 10:01
 23    null   null     9    null    9/24/2018 10:01
 23    null   null    12    null    9/24/2018 10:01
 25    null   null   null     4     9/24/2018 10:01
```

Try this query with the filter in the `WHERE` clause and `UNION` statements to collect it as one query result:

```
SELECT Index, Val AS Col1, NULL AS Col2, NULL AS Col3, NULL AS Col4, DateAndTime
FROM Table
WHERE Index=5 --First row is in Col1
  AND DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DateAndTime)=@daycnt
  AND DATEPART(HOUR,DateAndTime)=@hourcnt

UNION

SELECT Index, NULL AS Col1, Val AS Col2, NULL AS Col3, NULL AS Col4, DateAndTime
FROM Table
WHERE Index=9   --2nd row is in col 2
  AND DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DateAndTime)=@daycnt
  AND DATEPART(HOUR,DateAndTime)=@hourcnt

UNION

SELECT Index, NULL AS Col1, NULL AS Col2, Val AS Col3, NULL AS Col4, DateAndTime
FROM Table
WHERE Index=23   --row 3 and 4 are in Col 3
  AND DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DateAndTime)=@daycnt
  AND DATEPART(HOUR,DateAndTime)=@hourcnt

UNION

SELECT Index, NULL AS Col1, NULL AS Col2, NULL AS Col3, Val AS Col4, DateAndTime
FROM Table
WHERE Index=25
  AND DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DateAndTime)=@daycnt
  AND DATEPART(HOUR,DateAndTime)=@hourcnt
```

To yield this result (identical to the first query):

```
Index  Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4    DateAndTime
-----  ----   ----   ----   ----    -----------------
  5      6    null   null   null    9/24/2018 10:01
  9    null     1    null   null    9/24/2018 10:01
 23    null   null     9    null    9/24/2018 10:01
 23    null   null    12    null    9/24/2018 10:01
 25    null   null   null     4     9/24/2018 10:01
```

You mentioned that you would like to do an `INSERT`. The syntax for the `CASE` query is very similar.  Just put your `INSERT` statement before Your `CASE` query. However, if you wanted to stick with the `UNION` syntax, I still think the query would be easier to troubleshoot because you could make it into 4 separate `INSERT` queries instead of one `INSERT` with a big `UNION` query.

Comment: This query works, but how do I get it to play nice within an `INSERT INTO`? I was trying `INSERT INTO #temptable (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4)` and then using 4 of your `SELECT `statements but that doesn't seem to be the correct syntax. Thats why I tried to use CASE WHEN

Comment: I have two columns shown: `Val`, `DateAndTime`. If there are other columns in `[Table]` that you need, they would go in your `SELECT` clause.  I modified my example to show what I mean.

Comment: Are you thinking something like: if `Index`= 23, then `Val` goes in `col1`, but if `Index`= 24 then `Val` goes in `col2`?

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?